# How to get DateTime in yyyymmddhhmmss

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have written the below query to create an xml from entity, I need to get date time in .NET in `yyyymmddhhmmss` format for the field `SLOTTINGTIME`, so I have thought of writing a new method to get date time in desired format.

```
var slottingmessagexml = new XDocument(new XElement("Message",
    new XAttribute("ID","SLT"),
    new XElement("Record",
        new XAttribute("STORENO",slottingmessage.StoreID),
        new XAttribute("PICKLOCATION",slottingmessage.PickLocation),
        new XAttribute("TPNB",slottingmessage.ProductID),
        new XAttribute("SLOTTINGTIME",GetDateTimeInNewFormat(slottingmessage.SlottingDateTime)),
        new XAttribute("SLOTTTINGACTION",slottingmessage.SlottingAction))
    )
);
```

Comment: The answer is in your question title! well almost... `string newDate = myDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: ok, the question arises: you you want `yyyymmddhhmmss` (as you specified in the question) or `yyyyMMddhhmmss` ?

Comment: The below query? Which query?

Comment: Is this XML for consumption by some other system that you don't control? I ask because there's a standard for XML datetime values, which you should use if you can. If you can, consider using XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
```

If 24hr format is required that use uppercase `HH` inplace of `hh` in the format string.

Remember the first `MM` **should be in upper case** as lower case `mm` is for minutes where as uppercase is for Month.

For your particular case instead of writing a new method you can do:

```
new XAttribute("SLOTTINGTIME",slottingmessage.SlottingDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")),
```

One more thing to add: The output will contain Hour in 12 hours format because of the lower case `hh` part in the string. Not really sure if you need that because without AM/PM this can't indicate the accurate time. For that purpose use `HH` for hours which will display hours in 24 hour format. So your code could be:

```
new XAttribute("SLOTTINGTIME",slottingmessage.SlottingDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")),
                                                                               //^^ for 24 hours format
```

Comment: geez, give me a chance! ... it is unlikely they want 12 hour formatted as they are not using AM/PM

Comment: @musefan so you downvoted every answer so that you'll have priority over others?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: I don't have an answer

Comment: @musefan, its not sure, and based on the question and I am not entirely sure if that is the requirement, doesn't deserve a downvote IMO

Comment: @Habib: But you felt the need to presume the wanted months (MM) inbetween the year and day. I feel that is a correct assumption. But I think it is also fair to assume that they want 24 hour format, because without it there is no way to differentiate.

Comment: @musefan, because that seem like a mistake. Since you would not see year minutes day ... , but year month day, and may be time in 12 hours format. But I have modified the answer with 24 hr format as well.

Comment: Indeed, it does seem like a mistake. But to me, a 12 hour time format with no AM/PM designator also seems like a mistake, and just as important

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
public string GetDateTimeInNewFormat(DateTime d)
{
    return d.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
}
```

Or, for 24h format:

```
public string GetDateTimeInNewFormat(DateTime d)
{
    return d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
}
```

Comment: Updated answer (though I'm not sure downvoting based on what the OP "probably" wants is entirely fair ;))

Comment: Maybe, but you did also answer based on what the OP "probably" wants to... maybe they wanted minutes in between year and day :P (highly unlikely I know)

Comment: I can see where you're coming from but I'd say the assumption that yyyyMMdd is supposed to be sequential is more robust than the assumption that they are necessarily interested in whether the time is AM or PM, given that we have no knowledge of the domain.

Comment: You are right, we don't know their requirement. But we can easily see they are very new to formatting dates so I feel a good answer needs to contain a decent amount of effort to explain the mistakes (or potential mistakes). Your edit was fine for me which is why I changed from a downvote to an update. I think even if the OP wants 12 hour format, they should be encourage to change that requirement and the reasons why explained

Answer (score 0):

Although your question does not explicitly say what format you are looking for, I think that based on your example format of `yyyymmddhhmmss` we can assume that you want `[years][months][days][hours][minutes][seconds]`.

Based on that, we can break each part down as follows:

**Years**: If you want the full year then your `yyyy` is correct and will prduce `2013` for example. A common (although not encouraged) alternative could be `yy` (e.g. `13`)

**Months**: Currently your attempt of `mm` does not return months. It will produce the minutes. You likely want `MM` (e.g. `04`). Alternative include `MMM` (e.g. `APR`) and `MMMM` (e.g. `April`)

**Days**: Again you have this correct already. `dd` will produce `18` for example.

**Hours**: Your attempt of `hh` will produce a 12-hour time format. If this is what you are after then fine. But given that you have not attempted to include an AM/PM designator (with can be done with `tt` by the way) then I would recommend you opt for the 24-hour format which is `HH` (upper-case)

**Minutes**: You are correct with your minutes, `mm` will produce `52` for example.

**Seconds**: Again, `ss` is correct and will produce `33` for example.

---

Now we can string them all together and produce the following format, which includes the 24-hour time format which I would recommend. This can then be passed to the `DateTime` objects `ToString()` function like so:

```
var stringDateTime = slottingmessage.SlottingDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

If you wanted to maintain your approach of the `GetDateTimeInNewFormat` method, then you can implement it like so:

```
public string GetDateTimeInNewFormat(DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
}
```

This function would then be called the same way you already have in your example code:

```
GetDateTimeInNewFormat(slottingmessage.SlottingDateTime)
```

You can read more information about the various [date/time formatting options here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) where there are plenty of examples

Comment: +1, its a pretty well written answer with details as well, I am surprised why it got downvoted. Downvoter(s) should leave a comment as well.